# Command prompt appearing during execution of a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tee

This is a simplified version of a script I use:
In its simplified version tt should read the file `input` line by line and then print it to the standard output and also write to a file `log`.

`input` file:

```
asas
haha
asha
hxa
```

The script (named `simple`):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=input
logfile="log"

exec > >(tee "$logfile")   # redirect the output to a file but keep it on stdout
exec 2>&1

DONE=false
until $DONE; do
read || DONE=true
  [[ ! $REPLY ]] && continue                      #checks if a line is empty

  echo "----------------------"

  echo $REPLY

done < "$FILE"
echo "----------------------"
echo ">>> Finished"
```

The output (on console):

```
-bash-3.2$ ./simple
-bash-3.2$ ----------------------
asas
----------------------
haha
----------------------
asha
----------------------
hxa
----------------------
>>> Finished
```

At this time I need to press enter to terminate the script. Notice that a command prompt `-bash-3.2$` showed up during execution.

I checked that those lines are to blame:

```
exec > >(tee "$logfile")   # redirect the output to a file but keep it on stdout
exec 2>&1
```

Without them the output is as expected:

```
-bash-3.2$ ./simple
----------------------
asas
----------------------
haha
----------------------
asha
----------------------
hxa
----------------------
>>> Finished
-bash-3.2$
```

What is more I don't need to press enter to terminate the script.
Unfortunately I need saving the output both to the console (stdout) and a log file.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tee` on the echo lines directly.

For example:

```
[ben@lappy ~]$ echo "echo and save to log" | tee -a example.log
echo and save to log
[ben@lappy ~]$ cat example.log 
echo and save to log
```

The `-a` argument to `tee` will append to the log.

Comment: Is it possible to fix that without modifying each `echo` in the whole script? The script is kind of big.

Comment: If you don't want to modify everything, and you don't mind logging _everything_, you can tee the script itself, e.g. `$ ./your_script.sh | tee -a $LOG_FILE.`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need it to pause and wait for user input use the pause command:

```
 pause
```

Comment: This doesn't answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that `tee "$logfile"` is being run asynchronously. When you use process substitution like that, the main script doesn't wait for the process to exit.

So the `until` loop runs, the main script exits, the shell prints the prompt, and then `tee` prints its output.

You can see this more easily with:

```
echo Something > >(sleep 5; cat)
```

You'll get a command prompt, and then 5 seconds later `Something` will appear.

There was a thread about this behavior in comp.unix.shell a couple of years ago. See it [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.shell/GqLNzUA4ulA/NrVSphvkDpAJ)

Comment: `When you use process substitution like that, the main script doesn't wait for the process to exit.` How can I make the main script wait for `tee` to complete?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.